# assign argument when calling a function in actionscript

Tags: actionscript

```
var callback = null;
addEventListener(Event.MouseDown, callback = function(e:Event){blabla....});
```

Can I assign arguments when calling a function?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464925/passing-parameters-to-event-listeners-handlers

Comment: Or [How to pass arguments into event listener function in flex/actionscript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406957/how-to-pass-arguments-into-event-listener-function-in-flex-actionscript/6407128#6407128)

Answer (score 0):

Of course. Try it this way instead.

```
var callback = function(e:Event, arg1, arg2) { blabla....};

addEventListener(Event.MouseDown, function(e) {  callback(e, 0, 1); } );
```

Or If I misunderstood your question, perhaps this way:

```
var callback = null;

addEventListener(Event.MouseDown, 

       callback = function(e:Event) { anotherfunction(arg1, arg2); });
```